# Do you know of any text editors that are dual paned?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

.. so I can text side by side without opening many instances?

Thanks!

Comment: Try Visual Studio Code.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1668071 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44523/text-editor-with-split-screen-option

Comment: I googled for 'dual-pane text editor linux'.

Comment: I DDG it and no reference to dual pane

Comment: `emacs` can split it's screen horizontally, vertically, both, ... . However, as I recall, there is a significant learning curve.

Comment: You could try ultra edit or 7edit.  I do believe they both have that functionality.

Answer (score 5):

From my personal experience I can recommend to use **Kate** (`sudo apt-get install kate`) - it has many options in *View → Split View*:

[image: Kate - Split View]

---

Also you can try **JEdit** (`sudo apt-get install jedit`), it allows to have splits in *View → Splitting*:

[image: Jedit - Splitting]

or **Notepadqq** (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install notepadqq`), it has *View → Move/Clone Current Document → Move to Other View* option:

[image: Notepadqq - Move to Other View]

or **JuffEd** (`sudo apt-get install juffed-plugins`), it has *Move to the right panel* and *Move to the left panel*:

[image: JuffEd]

Comment: I haven't tried Kate but I hear it is top heavy. I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is **Geany**, available in the repositories.

Under `Tools`, click on `Plugin Manager` and enable `Split Windows`. The plugin for enabling split windows comes pre-installed.

[image: Plugin Manager]

You'll see the `Split Window` option under `Tools`.

[image: choosing split windows]

And that's it. Of course, you can choose between horizontal and vertical and drag the splitter to resize panes.

[image: Geany in split window mode]

Geany, in 18.04, is a gtk3 application and in 16.04, a gtk2 application. So, if your distro is "GNOME-based", you may prefer it as it pulls in very few dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, I tried geany and liked it but I settled for bluefish as it was a lot more customization. It does have split screen but not sure if that worked however it suited me in different ways. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Image of vim text editor with two files open]

Can be done in vim. They are called windows (`:help windows`)

Open new file vertically with `:vsplit /path/to/file` `:vs` for short. Use only `:vs` to open the current buffer in another window (so you can look at the same file in another place)

Open horizontally with `:split /path/to/file` `:sp` for short. Using only `:sp` will open the same file but horizontally

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> will cycle through the open windows. `:bn` will change to the next buffer in a window. (`:bp` will go to the previous buffer)

To close the active window `:close`

To dig deeper `:help close`, `:help split`, or `:help any-command` will open the help file in a new window and you can read more about them (`:close` will close the open window ;) )

[How to close vim from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24406/how-to-close-vim-from-the-command-line) (For the uninitiated.)

**Note:** The "Tab list" on the top is from the [airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin with the code below added to my .vimrc

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1 " Enable the list of buffers
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Atom](https://atom.io)

[image: Atom text editor]

Atom is a nice text editor packed with lots of powerful features and extension support, entirely written using Node JS and web technologies.